# python _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to run the existing project in centos machine.I installed packages from requirements.txt and it installed sucessfully.But while run "`python manage.py runserver`" i am getting the following traceback.

```
[root@localhost bv]# python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x98da9ec>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 415, in get_server_version
    self.cursor().close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/utils/tracking/__init__.py", line 9, in wrapped
    return callback(original, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql.py", line 21, in cursor
    result = original(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.set_character_set(charset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 294, in set_character_set
    super(Connection, self).set_character_set(charset)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

Need help to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: re-install python-mysql

Comment: @NileshG why re-install python-mysql. Mysql is configured properly i am able to see the database via command prompt.I installed mysql connector 1.2.3.More i installed mysql and python separately.

Comment: If i run syncdb also,i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute many sql sentence, don't user `cur.execute(sql)`

The better way is use `cur.executemany(sql)`

exp 1: this will cause some error

```
sql = "insert into test(name, age) value('Joe', '28');insert into test(name, age) value('xxtime', '15');"
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
```

exp 2: you can use this to instead

```
  sql = "insert into test(name, age) value(%s, %s);"
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql,[('Joe', '28'),('xxtime', '15')])
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try running on existing DB -

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

This will output new models.py, now compare the newly generated models.py with your models.py

Comment: I double checked now.I am getting the same error in question  while running this command.Need help to solve.